REGEX expression for XML tag in NetSuite saved search
Hope someone can assist here.
I have a LONG TEXT field which holds the extract of a XML file. I want to be able to report on this field inside a saved search, extracting the value of the 'Country' tag.
Example below:

I tried this particular regex expression and with no luck:
REGEXP_SUBSTR({custrecord_xml}, '<Country>([^<]+)</Country>', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
Can you identify what I am doing wrong here?
EDIT: Adding another screenshot to show the country tag:


You have no Country tag in your input.

In Oracle, SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('<Country>DE</Country>', '<Country>([^<]+)</Country>', 1, 1, NULL, 1) works well.

The issue is probably the unescaped / in your regex.  Update it with that character escaped using \:
REGEXP_SUBSTR({custrecord_xml}, '<Country>([^<]+)<\/Country>', 1, 1, NULL, 1)

